# ListView getting image value from SQLite lagging

Tags: android, sqlite

My app experiences lagging when I directly get data from a SQLite column. When I directly add the reference to an image when using ImageView it works great. Would threading solve this issue or is there another way to update images from a SQLite DB.

I'm pulling the data from SQLite and populating an ArrayList. If using only an ArrayList that is populated with data the lagging does not occur.

```
       @Override   // Layout displayed with the ArrayAdapter (yListAdapter)
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup   parent) {

        View itemView = convertView;
        if (itemView == null) {
            itemView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.listlayout11, parent, false);
        }

        Store1 currentPos = StoredInfo.get(position);


        ImageView imageView1 = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.checkBoxIMG);


   }

   // This doesnt work
    imageView1.setImageResource(currentPos.getTheSelectVal());

   // This will work
   // imageView1.setImageResource(R.drawable.checkYes)
```

Comment: Did you think of storing images in byte[] and then extracting? I use Realm and this procedure helps me, without any lag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code

```
// Get the image from SQLite DB
        // We will just get the last image we just saved for convenience...
        public byte[] retreiveImageFromDB() {
            Cursor cur = mDb.query(true, IMAGES_TABLE, new String[]{IMAGE,},
                                   null, null, null, null,
                                   IMAGE_ID + " DESC", "1");
            if (cur.moveToFirst()) {
                byte[] blob = cur.getBlob(cur.getColumnIndex(IMAGE));
                cur.close();
                return blob;
            }
            cur.close();
            return null;
        }


    public class Utils {

        public static byte[] getImageBytes(Bitmap bitmap) {
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
            return stream.toByteArray();
        }

        public static Bitmap getImage(byte[] image) {
            return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(image, 0, image.length);
        }

        public static byte[] getBytes(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
            ByteArrayOutputStream byteBuffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            int bufferSize = 1024;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

            int len = 0;
            while ((len = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                byteBuffer.write(buffer, 0, len);
            }
            return byteBuffer.toByteArray();
        }

    }
```